# OpenShift node.js Error: listen EACCES

Tags: node.js, socket.io, port, openshift

I have been using OpenShift with node.js and socket.io. My code is:

```
server.listen(process.end.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000);
```

My code says that it returns port 8080.
However, I get this error:

```
 DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.is'
 Info: socket.io started
 warn:error raised: Error: listen EACCES
```

How can I fix this?
No other solution I can find works.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You also need to specify to bind to your OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP in your listen, as it is trying to bind to 0.0.0.0 by default, which is not allowed.

Something like:

```
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
server.listen( port, ipaddress, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I happened to find this out elsewhere and was about to post that solution here.

Comment: If you are using sailsjs then instead of ipaddress use host