# What config setting is necessary for SailJS to run on port 80

Tags: sails.js

I am running sailsjs on a ubuntu ec2 instance. It works fine on port 1337, however when I set the port to 80 I get:

```
warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES
error: Server doesn't seem to be starting.
error: Perhaps something else is already running on port 80?
debug: Lowering sails...
```

After finding [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974094/openshift-node-js-error-listen-eacces) I tried passing the host IP and port in `app.js` like this:
    require('sails').lift({port:80,host:'127.0.0.1'});

That didn't work either. I checked for other apps running on port 80 via the `netstat` command and there aren't any.

Comment: Actually, looks like my question is a dup of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947356/node-js-app-cant-run-on-port-80-even-though-theres-no-other-process-blocking-t?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to execute your app with sudo ?

The error code EACCES means you don't have proper permissions to run applications on that port. On Linux systems, any port below 1024 requires root access.

source : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947356/node-js-app-cant-run-on-port-80-even-though-theres-no-other-process-blocking-t)

Comment: Totally agree. Also a useful answer with some details about what to do to make node work on this ports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports